# SqlDataReader [0] is empty

Tags: asp.net, sql, sqldatareader

I'm wanting to display the first row of a `SqlDataReader` (its the only row/column the database returns) in a text field. I thought this was the correct syntax but i get 'no data' error. I can ensure that the sql query being used should definitely return an answer, i've checked it in SQL Server.

```
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(sqlQuery, sqlConnection);
sqlConnection.Open();
SqlDataReader reader = sqlCommand.ExecuteReader();
Label1.Text = reader[0].ToString();
```

`reader[0]` doesn't seem to show anything.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to actually read the data if I remember correctly using:

```
reader.Read()
```

Which you can iterate through or just use the first value.

Answer (score 2):

You need to call `read()` to move to the rows. It is usually used as

```
   while(reader.read())
   {
        // do something
   }
```

In you case put `reader.read()` before assigning to label.

**Also remember always to close it - so use it in `using` block. **

Answer (score 0):

Please read the documentation for DataReader. The indexer provides a value based on the ordinal/column number. As you have not started (or are) moving through the reader, it will be empty.